# Populate dropdown when editing a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown like in below:-

```
<form name="depositForm"  action="<?php echo site_url('ajax_funds/deposit_funds'); ?>" id="depositForm" class="page-form-main form-horizontal " autocomplete="off" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-4" ></label>
     <div class="col-sm-8 country-selector">
        <select id="country" name="country" class="input-control">
           <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
              <option value='<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>'><?php echo $country['short_name']; ?></option>
           <?php } ?>
        </select>
</div>
<script>
  country = 'AF';
 $('#country').selectize({
    allowEmptyOption: true,
    create: true
 });
 $("#country").change(function () {
   country = $("#country option:selected").val().toUpperCase();
});

$('#depositForm select[name="country"]').val(countryid); 
</script>
```

So what I want is when I'm editing this form I want the country to be populated. I was trying the below code for this:-

```
$('#depositForm select[name="country"]').val(countryid);
```

`countryid` has the the id of the country that will be populated and I alerted `countryid` and it has the correct id of that country but the problem is this code is not working. **countryid** is coming from a ajax get request.

Comment: Where are you writing this jQuery Code?

Comment: Also you can check if $('#depositForm select[name="country"]').length is returning 1, as I don't see any depositForm in this code, so not sure if that's the issue

Comment: **depositForm** is the id of the form. It's a long form so I did n't included the entire one.

Comment: I'm writing this jQuery code in the inside a function.

Comment: **$('#depositForm select[name="country"]').length** is returning 1.

Comment: Please show a proper [mcve].

Comment: @misorude I edited my question please check and let me know you need further information or not. thank you.

Comment: Since you are using selectize.js here, you might need to use its `setValue` method here, instead of just using .val() https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md

Answer (score 0):

I would Use Select2 (https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax). You just need to create a function that gets the list of countries to build your options.